# MySQL MyISAM sorting query makes it slower

Tags: mysql, performance, sorting, sql-order-by, myisam

I am using MySQL 5.1 on a Windows Server 2008 (with 4GB RAM) and have the following configuration:

I have 2 MyISAM tables. One is in 1 database (DB1) and has 14 columns, which are mostly varchar. This table has about 5,000,000 rows and is the DB1.games table below. It has a primary key on GameNumber (int(10)).

The other table is the DB2.gameposition and consists of the columns GameNumber (links to 
DB1.games) and PositionCode (int(10)). This table has about 400,000,000 rows and there is an index IX_PositionCode on PositionCode.

These 2 databases are on the same server.

I want to run a query on DB2.gameposition to find a particular PositionCode, and have the results sorted by the linking DB1.games.Yr field (smallint(6) - this represents a Year). This sorting of results I only introduced recently. There is an index on this Yr field in DB1.games.

In my stored procedure, I perform the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tblGameNumbers(GameNumber INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO tblGameNumbers(GameNumber) 
SELECT DISTINCT gp.GameNumber 
FROM DB2.gameposition gp 
WHERE PositionCode = var_PositionCode LIMIT 1000;
```

I just get 1000 to make it quicker

And then join it to the DB1.games table.

In order to generate an EXPLAIN from that, I took out the temporary table (I use in the stored procedure) and refactored it as seen in the inner subquery below:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * 
FROM DB1.games g 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT gp.GameNumber 
            FROM DB2.gameposition gp 
            WHERE PositionCode = 669312116 LIMIT 1000
   ) B ON g.GameNumber = B.GameNumber 
ORDER BY g.Yr DESC 
LIMIT 0,28
```

Running the EXPLAIN above, I see the following:

```
1, 'PRIMARY', '', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 1000, 'Using temporary; Using filesort'
1, 'PRIMARY', 'g', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'B.GameNumber', 1, ''
2, 'DERIVED', 'gp', 'ref', 'IX_PositionCode', 'IX_PositionCode', '4', '', 1889846, 'Using temporary'
```

The query used to be almost instant before I introduced the ORDER BY clause. Now, sometimes it is quick (depending on different PositionCode), but other times it can take up to 10 seconds to return the rows. Before I introduced the sorting, it was always virtually instantaneous. Unfortunately, I am not too proficient in interpreting the EXPLAIN output. Or how to make the query faster.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Without the `order by`, your `limit` means the first 28 results are returned and then the query stops.  With `order by`, all results need to be retrieved so they can be sorted and the first 28 returned.

The explain shows what MySql is doing:

```
sort 5000000 games records by yr
for each games record from sorted list
    get the games record by primary key (to get all the columns)
    read gamepositions by position code
        if it does not match gamenumber, discard it
        when 1000 matches found, stop reading
    end read
end for
```

Try this instead:

```
select distinct ... from gameposition gp
inner join games g on g.gamenumber = gp.gamenumber
where gp.positioncode = ...
order by g.yr limit ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply...I am sorting only 1000 rows (as I'm limiting them to 1000) so I do not see why this should take long...and I need to get these 1000 rows before I limit them, otherwise the ORDER BY won't make sense...

Comment: Unfortunately MySQl is not using what we can see is the most efficient algorithm.  See updated answer.

Comment: SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT GameNumber
FROM DB2.gameposition
) gp
inner join games g on g.gamenumber = gp.gamenumber
WHERE PositionCode = 669312116
order by g.yr DESC limit 0,28 but this takes really long as the "Where" clause is applied AFTER the join...thus effectively joining two very large tables...

Comment: If I place the following (SELECT DISTINCT gp.GameNumber 
FROM DB2.gameposition gp WHERE PositionCode = 669312116 LIMIT 1000) I am joining on, into a physical table (tmp) and run: EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM DB1.games g INNER JOIN tmp B ON g.GameNumber = B.GameNumber 
ORDER BY g.Yr DESC LIMIT 0,28 the execution plan becomes much better (no derived, filesort or temporary). In sp I am creating a temporary table, inserting the 1000 matching GameNumbers there, and then joining as above. Is the execution plan affected by whether you join to a physical table or to a temporary table? Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that both the phsyical table tmp (that I used for testing) and the temporary table in the stored procedure have the following field: GameNumber UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY. So maybe the primary key makes the join faster than in the query modified for EXPLAIN (the one with the subquery). If that is the case, I still do not understand why sometimes it is slow...